# Error Running Gradle build - ionic cap run

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a problem several days ago, I work in ubuntu and I would appreciate it very much if you help me :( I have a personal project that is finished and I want to get the apk, when I create the apk with ionic cap build I don't get any error, just a warn of Plugins are missing dependencies which I don't think is a problem, worse when I run ionic cap run and select the device either external or emulator I get Running Gradle build - failed! and at the end An error occurred while running thread capacitor. ionic cap build warning ionic cap run ERROR Also when I create the apk android studio opens automatically and I get this message: Error: Android Studio

[WARNING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsDeP.png)

[ERROR BUILD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dklky.png)

[Error Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeFeP.png)

I already tried deleting the node_modules folder, installing android studio, node, java,
*gradle although I don't know if it installed correctly*, etc.

Comment: Kindly post your Warnings/errors in code block here, instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st image: You're missing the es6-promise-plugin. you need to install it

2nd and 3rd image: you are using an old version of gradle, which it is making it incompatible with what the compiler uses (8+). You need to install new version of gradle.